# user management framework for app engine python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, frameworks, user-management

Here are a few user management frameworks I've read about:

- GAE Sessions
- Flask Login
- gae-init (uses Flask)
- Beaker
- GAE Utilities
- gmemsess
- suas

Is there a library that is widely adopted in the python app engine community?

Thanks.

Edit: I should be more specific about what I am looking for. I am looking for a framework that will handle user registration, login, password reset, sticky sessions, custom fields for users, takes advantage of memcache for faster session lookup, and of course do all of this securely and simply.

I'd like to be able to specify my user model, and have an api such as:

```
// If this decorator fails, this function will return some value to signify the user is not logged in.
@user_management_api.authenticate_user
def some_func(user):
    // Get the user model data.
    name = user.name
    // etc.

// To return a session key to the application (ios, android, webapp, etc) for a sticky session.
@user_management_api.login
def login(user):
    return user_management_api.get_session_key()

def register():
    user_management_api.register_user()

@user_management_api.authenticate_user
def reset_user_password():
    user_management_api.reset_user_password()
```

Comment: I haven't seen anything widely adopted.  I have used repoze.who/what on a non public application on appengine that has over 2000 users.  The model used in repoze.who/what is very similiar to pyramid.  Which could also be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

The libraries we use for Google App Engine are [webapp2](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/), [jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/), [WTForms](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/1.0.4/), and [babel](http://babel.edgewall.org/) for localization. Some frameworks just bundle these components and call it a framework, then I think it's better to take the components right aways and make your own framework since flask for instance mostly just combines these components to make its framework.